# Do the words "mommy and daddy" in the following paragraph need to be in plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> I saw the young faces of several 10/12-year-old girls slowly turning purple with a pair of large tightening hands wrapped around their tiny porcelain necks.
> Tears were streaming down their soft silky cheeks, silently yet futilely calling **mommy and daddy** to their rescue.

I feel like if not in the plural, "mommy and daddy" would imply all those girls share the same parents.

Comment: It would also seem, and much more strangely, that they were being strangled simultaneously by the same pair of "large tightening hands". Wherever this comes from it seems to me that the use of singular words for parents (which I interpreted as meaning each girl appealing to her own parents) is the least of the difficulties with this piece of writing.

Comment: It is still incoherent writing. And downright comical (instead of being sad) at places. I've never seen or heard _soft silky cheeks_ calling out for help. :)

Comment: @user405662, Thank you! How about this version then: I saw in sequence the young faces of several 10/12-year-old girls slowly turning purple with a pair of large tightening hands wrapped around their tiny porcelain necks, and their soft silky cheeks moistened by two streams of silent tears, futilely calling mommy and daddy to their rescue.

Comment: @Jaden Wong— Proofreading is off-topic. Sorry. Moreover, I'm no great shakes at it. :)

Comment: It might also be noted that the sentence structure says that "tears" streaming down their cheeks .... were "silently...calling Mommy and Daddy." I think their *eyes* might silently call, but not their tears.

Comment: There's a good deal of latitude in English whether to use singular or plural in such situations. There are a lot of idioms like "cry wolf" (meaning to shout "wolf") which use a singular, and calling mommy is almost in the same category. The singular makes it more personal and individual, the plural suggests you're going to get a big mob of parents coming down to set them all free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to make the mentioned words plural
because the girls are individually calling their own parents, not others parents